# Firebase rules to allow read by a user with an admin role

Tags: json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

Hey I was think of having the user role ("admin" / "user") under the users data.
But at the same time I'd like the user itself to be able to edit it's own user data, but (of cause) not change its own role, unless it is admin already?

I can't seem to get the following to work. Any help would be appreciated.

```
{
    "rules": {
        "$others":{
          ".read": true,  
          ".write": "auth != null",
        },
        "users": {
          "$company":{
                "$uid": {
                    ".read": "auth != null && ($uid === auth.uid || root.child('users').child($company).child(auth.uid).child('role').val() == 'admin')",
                    ".write": "auth != null && ($uid === auth.uid ||root.child('users').child($company).child(auth.uid).child('role').val() == 'admin')",
                      "role":{
                        ".write": "auth != null && root.child('users').child($company).child(auth.uid).child('role').val() == 'admin'",
                      }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the minimal code for a read operation that doesn't work?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thanks. I tried under the simulator in Firebase console.
 I could still instead role:"admin" as a normal user. But I think I'll take another approach and make a "roles" node like users.

Comment: Remember to present code in your question.

Comment: Hmm. See above comment from @Frankvanpuffelen. I asked for clarification as your /users node has a company node as a child and then a uid as a child of that... Typically it would be /users/uid/which_company:company; but it depends on  your use case. This may possibly be a good opportunity to denormalize the node which would simplify the rules considerably.

Comment: @Jay denormalized the roles into its own node which works. Ty